# MongoDB updating fields in array

Tags: php, mongodb, database

How can I set "album1" to "my Album" in the `albums` array? I only know its `_id`.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4f41a5c7c32810e404000000"),
    "albums": {
    "0": {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545d1bc328103812000000"),
        "name": "album1" 
    },
     "1": {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545f56c328103c12000000"),
        "name": "album2" 
    },
    "2": {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545f68c328103012000000"),
        "name": "album3" 
    },
    "3": {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f546642c328103c12000001"),
        "name": "album4" 
    }
}
```

Comment: read this http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is not correct. If you need an array you should define it as such rather than make it a map (which is what it is at the moment since your array indices are actually keys).

Convert to an array :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4f41a5c7c32810e404000000"),
    "albums": [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545d1bc328103812000000"),
        "name": "album1" 
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545f56c328103c12000000"),
        "name": "album2" 
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545f68c328103012000000"),
        "name": "album3" 
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("4f546642c328103c12000001"),
        "name": "album4" 
    }]
}
```

And then update using positional operator :

```
db.col.update({'albums._id':..}, {$set:{'albums.$.name':"My Album"}})
```

Note that using _id in an embedded element is confusing at best.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I would try is later!!